# How to find the best features efficiently?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am looking to find the best possible model for predicting a target variable (categorical, 9 classes), using up to 30 available features. I have a dataset with 12k rows.

When I worked on similar problems previously, I had access to high-performance computing clusters, meaning that I didn't have to worry too much about resource constraints when tuning a model. Now, I'm restricted to using a 2021 M1 Macbook Pro, or a less powerful Ubuntu server. This is proving a huge challenge, as everything I try is ending up taking way too long to be feasibly used.

I started the process by running a very basic shoot-out cross-validation between 7 possible classifiers, employing all available features. This led to 3 potential classifiers (SVC-linear, random forest, multinomial logistic regression), all of which have returned mean accuracy values around .73 (which isn't bad, but I'm aiming for >.8.

**Now, I want to find the best possible model configuration by a) finding the best feature combo for each model, and b) the best hyperparameters.**

I've tried two strategies for feature selection:

**One** - `mlextend`'s `SequentialFeatureSelector`, utilising all available processor cores. For only one model (SVC), ***this process ran for >30 hours***, and then crashed the entire system. Not a feasible strategy.

**Two** - I tried using a more statistical approach `SelectKBest`, without having to test every possible feature combination. This is the code that came up with to do that:

```py
rnd = RANDOM_STATE
model_feature_performance_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i, clf in enumerate(classifiers):
    for f in range(folds):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
            X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True, random_state=rnd)
        
        for k in range(1, len(X.columns)+1):
            selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=k)

            selector.fit(X_train, y_train)

            X_train_selected = selector.transform(X_train)
            X_test_selected = selector.transform(X_test)

            clf.fit(X_train_selected, y_train)
            y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_selected)

            f1 = np.round(f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted'), 3)
            acc = np.round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 3)

            features_used = ', '.join(list(X_train.columns[selector.get_support()]))

            tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(
                [{
                    'classifier': clf_names[i],
                    'fold': f,
                    'random_state': rnd,
                    'k': k,
                    'features': features_used,
                    'f1': f1,
                    'acc': acc
                }]
            )

            model_feature_performance_df = pd.concat([model_feature_performance_df, tmp_df])

        rnd += 1
```

Again, after over 24 hours, it had only completed one fold for the SVC model, and then it crashed without returning anything.

I am looking for any advice as to how to make an informed decision on what my best possible model could be within hours, not days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two approaches are indeed standard approaches when selecting features.

Please note that when using `SelectKBest`, or any univariate feature selection method, each feature is evaluated independently, without considering potential relationships between features. This might not result in the "best" combiantion of features.

Please have a look at the scikit-learn website, they have an extensive guide on feature selection there: [1.13. Feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) I couldn't explain it better or give a more comprehensive overview.